# Mounting sshfs from pc behind VPN

Tags: reverse-proxy, sshfs

What is the best way to mount sshfs drives from machine behind VPN on a laptop while on travel?
There is PC 'B' with VPN always on and non-VPN PC 'A' whitelisted on 'B' for local traffic.
A->B is ssh paswordless autenthication (key stored)

I tried mesh and it is slow and drops connection.
What the command for 1-hop ssh would be?